If I delete my OS can I mint token again?
I made an spl-token on my laptop.
I want to delete my Linux system and install windows.
So after that, because I made a token on my Linux system, i can't access my token as owner and mint more tokens?

If you used the default Solana toolchain (https://docs.solanalabs.com/cli/install), you probably used the default keypair generated at ~/.config/solana/id.json to create the token.
The id.json is the private key (key pair) that allows you to access the token (unless a different one is defined in CLI).

Verify
# Check the public key managed by the keypair in id.json
solana-keygen pubkey ~/.config/solana/id.json

# Check the mint authority of your token
spl-token display -um <token-address>

If the public key of id.json matches the mint authority, then id.json is the file you need to back up.

Backup
Back up id.json as it is the only way to access your token after reinstallation. After reinstalling the system, you can use your backed-up keypair and copy it to the Windows system (https://github.com/LearnWithArjun/solana-env-setup/blob/main/windows_setup.md#-install-solana).


